# Плагины WordPress. Что изменилось?

Tags: wordpress

На странице Плагинов в Wordpress появились какие то ошибки сверху. Такого у меня никогда не было. Как это убрать? Почему это появилось?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А после чего это появилось? Или вдруг не было и внезапно появилось?

Comment: Тесты ошибок показывайте текстом а не картинками. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, повреждены файлы темы nilsen. Попробуйте ее переустановить.